# Read first 3000 bytes of a text file in php

Tags: php

Solved! I used an existing json file that I was using to display diagrams on the page.

I have a 2000 line text file. I want to read in the first 3000 bytes to a php variable. This works, but only at the cost of reading in the entire text file:

```
$little_diagrams = ('assets/diagrams.txt'); $mason = file($little_diagrams);
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work. Any ideas on why?

```
$little_diagrams  = file_get_contents("assets/diagrams.txt", NULL, NULL, 0, 3000);

$mason = file($little_diagrams);
```

The trouble is that I have to process lines in "assets/diagrams.txt" such as:
  2833|6979|Poloskov|||Nikolayev|Igor|2272|1n3rk1/3p1ppp/5q2/2p1P3/2B2P2/r2Q2P1/1b2N2P/1R3K1R|

2832|6979|Poloskov|||Nikolayev|Igor|2272|r2qk2r/1b1p1ppp/n4b2/2pN4/2B1P3/8/PP3PPP/R2QK1NR|
2831|6978|Nikolayev|Igor|2272|Buturin|Vladimir (IM)|2405|r3r1k1/1ppb1pp1/3p1n1p/2nP4/p3P3/4NP2/PPBN1KPP/R3R3|
    2830|6978|Nikolayev|Igor|2272|Buturin|Vladimir (IM)|2405|r2qr1k1/1ppb1pp1/p1np1n1p/8/3PP3/4NN2/PPB2PPP/R2Q1RK1|

2829|6977|Nikolayev|Igor|2272|Tabatadze|Tamaz|2288|2rqk2r/4bp1p/p1n1b3/3pP3/Pp1P2p1/1P3p2/1B2NPPP/2RQNRK1|

2828|6976|Lutsko|Igor|2307|Nikolayev|Igor|2272|6r1/1pp2p1k/p2p3p/2bP4/2P2r2/1P4NP/P2R1P1K/5R2|

NEW CODE: (doesn't work, no diagrams are displayed at http://communitychessclub.com/ left column bottom)

```
$filename = "assets/diagrams.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$little_diagrams = fread($handle, 3000);  //<<--- as per your need 

fclose($handle);


$X = 5000; $line = 0;

foreach($little_diagrams as $line) {$X++; if ($X >= 5040) {break;} $token = explode("|", $line); //etc

}
```

Comment: Please define _"it doesn't work"_

Comment: The variable $mason echos as nothing. I need it as a data text file to print diagrams.

Comment: Does the file exist at that path? Try `is_readable('assets/diagrams.txt')`. Also make sure you can [see any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php). `file_get_contents()` returns `false` if something goes wrong

Comment: Urgh, I see what's wrong now. Just assign `$mason = file_get_contents(...`. You are attempting to run the file content string through `file()` which is not a file path. This will not work

Comment: read this article, https://www.sitepoint.com/performant-reading-big-files-php/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: @BilalAhmed I don't think OP needs to worry about reading <3kb of file contents

Comment: _"file_get_contents() reads it in as one line"_ <- no it doesn't. Are you looking at the result in an HTML document by chance?

Comment: 3000 bytes seems quite arbitrary give you appear to be parsing delimited, structured data. I suggest you have a look at [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
   $filename = "c:\\files\\yourfile.txt";
   $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
   //$little_diagrams = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
   $little_diagrams = fread($handle, 3000);  //<<--- as per your need 

   fclose($handle);
?>
```

Try above code and read this `fread` [function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

I hope this will help also see the example code **Example #2 Binary fread() example**

`fread` takes two arguments

`string fread ( resource $handle , int $length )`

second is length part

`length bytes have been read` as per documentation

**fread() reads up to length bytes from the file pointer referenced by handle. Reading stops as soon as one of the following conditions is met:**

---

**UPDATED BELOW**

**Note:
You can use file_get_contents() to return the contents of a file as a string.**

**change second argument to FALSE from NULL** then try hope it will work

so in my opinion correct code will be like below take a try

```
<?php
                                         //however working with null also
    $file_content =file_get_contents('demoTest.txt',FALSE,NULL,0,3000);

    echo 'File Size: '.filesize('demoTest.txt');
    echo '<br/> CONTENT HERE<br />'.$file_content;

    echo '<br /><br />String Length: '.strlen($file_content);
?>
```

read the [documentation at here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) for `file function`

[image]

Comment: Your first example is fine but your _"UPDATED BELOW"_ part contains the same error that OP has; `file()` takes a file-path, not the contents of a file

Comment: @Phil Thanks For clarification. You are right. Response updated.

Comment: Still looks broken to me. It should be `$mason = file_get_contents("assets/diagrams.txt", FALSE, NULL, 0, 3000);`. There is absolutely no use for `file()` in this at all

Comment: _"`// it dosent; work you are right phil`"_ <- If it doesn't work, don't put it in your answer; you'll only confuse people. Nice update and example though. I'd upvote again if I could ;)

Comment: Sorry @Phil but this time image output is attached